# Creating duplicate rows based on list in another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of project numbers in a sheet and a list of organization numbers in another. I want to duplicate each project number row for every organizational number. It would look like this:

**Starting Project Table**

```
PROJECT  EFF_DATE END_EFF_DATE DESCRIPTION
420000  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 1  
420007  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 2
420008  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 3
```

**Starting Order Number Table**

```
Order Number
3710
3700
3715
```

Resulting Table after Macro/VBA is run

```
PROJECT  EFF_DATE END_EFF_DATE DESCRIPTION  Order Number
420000  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 1     3710
420007  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 2     3710
420008  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 3     3710
420000  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 1     3700
420007  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 2     3700
420008  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 3     3700
420000  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 1     3715
420007  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 2     3715
420008  1/11/2015   12/30/3000  Project 3     3715
```

I have tried messing around with macros and vba with not a lot of success. Any advice/thoughts? I would like it to be automated if possible with the result being a new sheet that has the sorted information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is what i got so far. in case your two sheets are sorted this code will satisfy your needs.

However, on the third sheet you have provide a title row like you have it in your result example.

```
Sub sortProj()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, z As Integer

    i = 2
    z = 2
    While ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        j = 2
        While ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1) <> ""
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Copy

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(z, 1).Insert
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(z, getEmptyCol) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1)
            z = z + 1
            j = j + 1
        Wend
        i = i + 1
    Wend



End Sub

Function getEmptyCol() As Double

    Dim a As Integer
    a = 1
    While ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(1, a) <> ""
        a = a + 1
    Wend

    getEmptyCol = a

End Function
```

Please leave a comment on how it worked.